# Как узнать сколько времени пользователь держал наведенной мышку на блок? jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте, как можно реализовать следующую функцию: есть код, например

```
$('.block').on('hover', function(){
  //timer
  alert('ok');
});
```

Как сделать, что бы "ок" появлялось только при определенном времени наведения на блок, например когда пользователь держит 1000 мс , в противном случае ничего не происходило?

Comment: если человек навел и сразу отвел курсор так что не был на нем одну секунду то `alert` не должно работать верно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Улучшенное решение товарища @Shnur с очисткой таймаута. Не являюсь любителем глобальных переменных, поэтому предлагаю записывать в dataset этого элемента запущенный id таймаута, при выходе - очищать таймаут.

```js
$('.block').hover(function() {
    $(this).data(
      'timeout',
      setTimeout(function() {
        console.log('ok');
      }, 1000));
  },
  function() {
    clearTimeout($(this).data('timeout'));
  });
```

```css
.block {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Отлично работает, спасибо большое за подсказку, сэкономил кучу времени)

Comment: работает всегда, даже если не был в блоке 1 секунду а меньше

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan пруф пожалуйста.

Comment: Не понял вашего ответа.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan доказательства, что мой код нерабочий, пожалуйста.

Comment: резко наведите курсор мыши на блок и отведите, `alert` все ровно работает, а если ты был в блоке меньше одной секунды то `alert` не должно срабатывать.

Comment: Я скинул ваш код в чистый `html` и оно не правильно сработало

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan не понимаю, что вы там куда скинули, но багу я увидел. Навести, убрать и навести заново в течении одной секунды - оно сработает. Теперь согласен.

Answer (score 2):

Вот так можно сделать

```js
var timerId;
$('.block').on('mouseover', function(){
  timerId = setTimeout(function(){
    alert('ok');
  }, 1000);
});

$('.block').on('mouseout', function(){
  clearTimeout(timerId);
});
```

```css
.block {
  background-color: #0000cc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: Правильный код.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#hover').hover( function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
  alert('ok');
  }, 1000)
  
  
});
```

```css
#hover {
width:100px;
height:100px;
background:linear-gradient(to top, #3AE2CE, #1BC1AE);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hover"></div>
```

Comment: Не правильный ответ, у вас просто за одну секунду после наведения срабатывает код и все